# Class verified does not exist, Email verification Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-5.7

I have updated my Laravel project from 5.6 to 5.7. Laravel 5.7 comes with the new email verification so I tried to build that in my new project. 
I folowed the instructions on the update guide from the Laravel docs, but after registering a new user on my site, I receive the message: `Class verified does not exist`. It does send me an email, so that part works just fine. But I think I'm missing something in my middleware, because the docs say we have to add: `Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);` instead of the original `Auth::routes();`

Did anybode had the same problem like I did?

Comment: Did you add 'implements MustVerifyEmail' to your User class and add ->middleware('verified') to the page you want to protect?

Comment: Yes, I did. Route::get('dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('home.dashboard')->middleware('verified'); And also the HomeController has a construct with: $this->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);

Comment: The verify link in the email also works just fine. I can verify my account and it updates the email_verified_at column in the DB with the current date.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ensure that you have registered the verified middleware in App\Http\Kernel.php:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
```

Comment: Sorry for my late response. Yes! This was the solution. Thank you very much!